# How do I install the Spark distribution using only Drush?

Tags: drush

How do I fire up the [Spark Distribution](http://drupal.org/project/spark) via a drush command?

Comment: `drush make build-spark.make ~/Sites/spark`...http://drupal.org/node/1741590

Comment: That seems an answer. `:)`

Comment: @kiam Feel free to put it in, I'm on mobile at the mo and it's fiddly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

Clive: `drush make build-spark.make ~/Sites/spark` - [Building Spark from Drush Make yourself](http://www.drupal.org/node/1741590)